# Turning on Abort Publishing/Unpublishing on All Servers in Case of Error publish option by default

Tags: publishing

In the advanced tab of the publish dialog window there is an option to 'Abort Publishing/Unpublishing on All Servers in Case of Error'. By default this option is turned off.

Is there a way to turn this option by default on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking of two possible scenarios:

- Event System - intercept the publish event `PublishEventArgs` on the item you are publishing and set the Publish Instruction property `RollbackOnFailure` to `true`. In this scenario,  the user won't have control over this feature. Rather, it is controlled by the code via Tridion API;
- GUI extension - extend the Publish Options view and set the checkbox using JavaScript. This scenario will show the checkbox selected by default and the user has control over enabling/disabling this option;

There might be a third option of modifying the actual HTML of the view (the hacky way), but I recommend against it, because it's not a supported path.

Answer (score 2):

There is no back end switch you can flip to do this.  You either need to extend the GUI via the Anguilla framework or hack the Tridion HTML source to set the checkbox on in the semantic markup.  In Tridion 2009 hacking the markup was a sure and easy way to do this (though unsupported since a new release could rewrite that source).